# How to update existing object or add new object of an array of objects conditionally using es6 in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to update my state with the given object (`action.payload`) if the id of both objects are matched. Otherwise I want to push the certain object into the following state. This is a Redux project so I want update my state immutably.

This is my code:

```js
import initialState from "./initialState";

import { ADD_TO_CART, DELETE_FROM_CART } from "./actionType";

const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const itemToAdd = action.payload;
      const existingItemIndex = state.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === itemToAdd.id
      );
      if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
        // If the item exists in the cart, update its quantity and cartQuantity
        return state.map((item) => {
          if (item.id === existingItemIndex) {
            return {
              ...item,
              quantity: itemToAdd.quantity - 1,
              cartQuantity: itemToAdd.cartQuantity + 1,
            };
          }
          return item;
        });
      } else {
        // If the item doesn't exist in the cart, add it with updated properties
        return [
          ...state,
          {
            ...itemToAdd,
            quantity: itemToAdd.quantity - 1,
            cartQuantity: itemToAdd.cartQuantity + 1,
          },
        ];
      }
    case DELETE_FROM_CART:
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

This is my result:

```js
cart = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "mackbook pro",
    category: "laptop",
    price: 16000,
    quantity: 9,
    imageUrl: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/7/thumbnail.jpg",
    cartQuantity: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "iphone13 pro max",
    category: "mobile phone",
    price: 12000,
    quantity: 19,
    imageUrl: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",
    cartQuantity: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Iphone 14 ",
    category: "mobile phone",
    price: 35666,
    quantity: 9,
    imageUrl: "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/3/thumbnail.jpg",
    cartQuantity: 1,
  },
];
```

This is the component where I use dispatch function:

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../redux/cart/actions";
export default function ProductItem({ product }) {
  const { id, name, category, price, quantity, imageUrl, cartQuantity } =
    product;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    dispatch(
      addToCart({
        id,
        name,
        category,
        price,
        quantity,
        imageUrl,
        cartQuantity,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='lws-productCard'>
      <img className='lws-productImage' src={imageUrl} alt='product' />
      <div className='p-4 space-y-2'>
        <h4 className='lws-productName'>{name}</h4>
        <p className='lws-productCategory'>{category}</p>
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between pb-2'>
          <p className='productPrice'>
            BDT <span className='lws-price'>{price}</span>
          </p>
          <p className='productQuantity'>
            QTY <span className='lws-quantity'>{quantity}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <button
          className='lws-btnAddToCart'
          onClick={() => handleAddToCart()}
          disabled={!quantity}
        >
          Add To Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is everytime I click existing product I want to update its counter and cart counter but it does not update its property.

Comment: What is the difference between `item.quantity` and `item.cartQuantity`, and why do you always subtract 1 from `quantity` and add 1 to `cartQuantity`? What specifically isn't working as expected? Please [edit] to clarify the reducer logic, what any specific issue is, and enough relevant code to be considered a complete [mcve].

Comment: my initialState is empty array. I want to add a new object to this array if the object is not exist. If the object is exist in the array I want to update it's property like subtract `1 from quantity and add 1 to cartQuantity.

Comment: That doesn't explain ***why*** you have two item quantity counts and ***why*** you add one to one and subtract one from the other. Is one of them supposed to be an item quantity in the cart and the other a total cart item count? This is probably a separate issue though. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that shows what the data is that you are dispatching to the store? We should see what the action payloads are that you are dispatching to the store.

Comment: So I have I productItem component. Each component have product details and 'add to cart' button. Every time when a user click this button I want to update my cart array (which is initialState) with the components object property. And also I want to update how many time user have clicked 'add to cart button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the way you're trying to update the existing item in the cart. You're checking if the item.id matches existingItemIndex, but existingItemIndex is an index, not an ID.

Here's the corrected code for the ADD_TO_CART case

```html
case ADD_TO_CART:
  const itemToAdd = action.payload;
  const existingItemIndex = state.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id === itemToAdd.id
  );
  if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
    // If the item exists in the cart, update its quantity and cartQuantity
    return state.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === existingItemIndex) {
        return {
          ...item,
          quantity: item.quantity - 1,
          cartQuantity: item.cartQuantity + 1,
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
  } else {
    // If the item doesn't exist in the cart, add it with updated properties
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        ...itemToAdd,
        quantity: itemToAdd.quantity - 1,
        cartQuantity: itemToAdd.cartQuantity + 1,
      },
    ];
  }
```

The main change is in this block:

```html
return state.map((item, index) => {
  if (index === existingItemIndex) {
    return {
      ...item,
      quantity: item.quantity - 1,
      cartQuantity: item.cartQuantity + 1,
    };
  }
  return item;
});
```

I've changed the condition from item.id === existingItemIndex to index === existingItemIndex since we want to compare the current index of the item being mapped to the existingItemIndex.